# Socket Errors while Setting up Non-Login SMTP Server for error email with Python

Tags: python, email, smtp, port, windows-server-2012

I have a python script that runs automatically weekly. I want the script to send an e-mail if it encounters an error (such as from a locked or missing file). For obvious security concerns, I don't want to use an external SMTP server that requires a login.

Using: Python 3 (script will run with Python 2.7.5 though, using 3 because my Spyder is configured to 3 and I prefer to write in it), Windows Server 2012

I believe my issue is a blocked port, but I'm inexperienced and can't really understand the responses I get from various nelnet commands. I want to verify that the python code I'm using, and the error I'm getting, is in fact due to a blocked port and not something else.

I run the code in python's base IDE using Run As Administrator. It returns: ('Unexpected error:', ).

I've tried with ports 25 & 80, but I'm basically shooting randomly at ports as I don't know if (1) that's the issue or (2) how to interpret the 20+ lines in the CMD I get when I put in netstat -an |find /i "25" for example.

```
    # Import modules
import sys, arcpy, datetime, traceback
import os
import shutil
# Import the email libraries
import smtplib, smtpd, asyncore, threading, ctypes

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

try:
    if is_admin():
        print("You an admin yay!")
        # set datetime variable
        d = datetime.datetime.now()
        sdeTempPath = r"C:\tempUSIC"
        if not os.path.exists(sdeTempPath):
            os.mkdir(sdeTempPath)
            print("Temporary directory not found. A new directory has been " + \
                  "created at {0}.".format(sdeTempPath))
        else:
            print("The temp USIC directory already exists at {0} and will be used.".format(sdeTempPath))    

        # open log file for holding errors
        # log code skipped


        ##--------Set up SMTP Server Local
        smtpServer = smtpd.SMTPServer(('localhost',80), None)
        loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncore.loop, name="Asyncore Loop")
        loop_thread.start()

        ##Set the Email Server Information-------------------
        # Set the server object that has the Outlook SMTP and port
        fromAddr = 'robert.domiano@spireenergy.com'
        toAddr = 'robert.domiano@spireenergy.com'
        text = 'This is a test of sending email from within python.'
        server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost',80)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.sendmail(fromAddr, toAddr, text)
        server.quit()
    else:
        # This is the python 3 version
        print("You not an admin boo.")
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)

####main code stuff skipped here####

except:
    #Rest of except code skipped
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Comment: Your code tries to connect to a SMTP server on localhost. Did you (or another admin for local machine) install such a server, which one, and how is it configured. If the answer to first question is no, then you must install one first.

Comment: Yes, there's a local host server setup. When I go to http:/ /localhost, it gets a page.

Comment: What you find at http://localhost is a HTTP server. SMTP is a different protocol. By default, no SMTP server is installed on a Windows system...

Comment: I believe I went through steps to make sure one was enabled, but I have absolutely no idea how to verify or check that there is one.